# magento simple products showing configurable price

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

From yesterday some of the products on my site are not updating when you click a size/colour option on the front end it still shows the configurable product price. However if you refresh the page it changes but it poses an issue as customers will they think a product is cheaper than it is.

I never had this problem before and all the products have been set up for more than a year and were working fine. We have been making adjustments to some of the attribute sets so I don't know if this has caused the issue.

It;s not happening to all the products and it just seems to happen sporadically and you can't always recreate it.

Any ideas would appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Meant to say I do use the simple configurable products extension

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have the JavaScript error? Did you check it?